# How can I avoid unnecessary expensive operations in my iterator implementation when some values are ignored?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits, lazy-evaluation, iterator-traits

I have an `Iterator` implementation that looks like this:

```
struct MyType {
    // stuff
}

struct Snapshot {
    // stuff
}

impl MyType {
    pub fn iter(&mut self) -> MyIterator {
        MyIterator {
            foo: self
        }
    }
}

struct MyIterator<'a> {
    foo: &'a mut MyType
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
    type Item = Snapshot;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.cheap_condition() {
           self.cheap_mutation();  // Inexpensive
           let s: Snapshot = self.snapshot();  // Expensive copying
           Some(s)
        } else {
           None
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine if I want to use every instance of `Snapshot` generated, but if I want to use something like `Iterator::step_by` or `Iterator::last`, where I don't care about the intermediate `Snapshot`s, the cost incurred by the generation of those unused values is a massive performance hit.

I *could* override every single method of `Iterator` such that the expensive operation only takes place when necessary, but I feel like there must be a simpler and more idiomatic way of doing this, or a way to lazily generate the `Snapshot` corresponding to an iteration from an intermediate type for `Item` if `Iterator::next` hasn't been called again.

I do not want to return references to `MyType`, because I want the `Snapshot`s that I *do* generate to have independent lifetimes, enabling, for example, the result of `Iterator::collect()` to outlive the instance of `MyType`.

Comment: *I could override every single method of Iterator such that the expensive operation only takes place when necessary* — I believe this is the correct solution.

Comment: If it is, then I guess there is no other option, and I guess I could add a function of some sort to avoid repeating the same code over and over, but I'd like to see if anyone has a better idea. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to override every `Iterator` method. The only relevant ones are `nth`, `last`, `count`, `step_by`, and `skip`. All the other methods require examining `Self::Item` in some way so you can't avoid generating `Snapshot`s for those. Luckily `step_by` and `skip` use `nth` internally, so that really only leaves us with `nth`, `count`, and `last` which we must override:

```rust
use core::marker::PhantomData;

struct Snapshot;

struct MyType<'a> {
    item: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> MyType<'a> {
    fn cheap_condition(&self) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
    fn cheap_mutation(&mut self) {
        todo!()
    }
    fn snapshot(&self) -> Snapshot {
        Snapshot
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyType<'a> {
    type Item = Snapshot;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.cheap_condition() {
            self.cheap_mutation(); // Inexpensive
            Some(self.snapshot()) // Expensive
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    // also covers skip & step_by methods
    fn nth(&mut self, n: usize) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        for _ in 0..n {
            if self.cheap_condition() {
                self.cheap_mutation();
            } else {
                return None;
            }
        }
        self.next()
    }

    fn count(mut self) -> usize
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        let mut count: usize = 0;
        while self.cheap_condition() {
            self.cheap_mutation();
            count += 1;
        }
        count
    }

    fn last(mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        while self.cheap_condition() {
            self.cheap_mutation();
            if !self.cheap_condition() {
                return Some(self.snapshot());
            }
        }
        None
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10e0a063735aca9f68eb1389bc7732b8)

If you want to make other `Iterator` methods like `filter` lazy by checking the predicate against `MyType<'a>` instead of `Snapshot` you have to define your own `Iterator`-like trait for that, as all the other methods only work on `Self::Item`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I wasn't sure about the inner implementations of `step_by` and such, so thanks for clarifying. I guess this is the correct answer, so I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Also relevant might be the `iter_advance_by` feature though it is currently not (yet) stable.
[Tracking Issue 77404](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/77404)

Comment: The implementation of `last` is wrong: if the iterator is empty it will reach the `unreachable!()` statement!